# Geolocation of Tweets using twitteR seems to be innacurate

Tags: r, twitter

I've been using the twitteR package to pull tweets (documentation can be found here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/twitteR/twitteR.pdf). I am trying to find tweets about a specific subject in a specific area, so I was using the geolocation field of searchTweets to limit my results, but it is returning tweets with very disparate locations, ones that are far outside of my search radius.

Here is my code.

```
twitteR::setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_secret)
tw = twitteR::searchTwitter('flu', n = 10000, geocode = '44.94,-93.18, 1mi')

tweets = twitteR::twListToDF(tw)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that [TweetR](https://github.com/geoffjentry/twitteR) is being "relatively leisurely" deprecated in favour of [rtweet](https://github.com/mkearney/rtweet). After some [simple authentication setup](http://rtweet.info/articles/auth.html)  for that library, I was able to do this:

```
library(rtweet)
rt <- search_tweets(geocode='44.94,-93.18,5mi')
rt
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 81 x 42
   status_id  created_at          user_id  screen_name text             source 
   <chr>      <dttm>              <chr>    <chr>       <chr>            <chr>  
 1 970008327… 2018-03-03 18:49:41 3264407… pschrades21 This is crazy b… Tweetb…
 2 970008317… 2018-03-03 18:49:39 1309321… dizzyizzie… @jamescharles Y… Twitte…
 3 970008309… 2018-03-03 18:49:37 1595660… martin_dev… @winnerbowzer c… Twitte…
 4 970008300… 2018-03-03 18:49:35 45193580 mattglions  You must not ha… Twitte…
 5 970008298… 2018-03-03 18:49:34 1830410… RedLetterM… "Make a grown m… Twitte…
 6 970008282… 2018-03-03 18:49:31 28681763 kirkshould… @Colinj76 And H… Twitte…
 7 970008267… 2018-03-03 18:49:27 4561314… TheTazMan5  RT @PiperBaseba… Twitte…
 8 970008260… 2018-03-03 18:49:25 2828856… luulayy     RT @ZAK_o0: Whe… Twitte…
 9 970008256… 2018-03-03 18:49:24 1009764… Yoo_ItsIma… So glad I let t… Twitte…
10 970008240… 2018-03-03 18:49:21 57181524 jwedlund    Congratulations… Twitte…
# ... with 71 more rows, and 36 more variables: reply_to_status_id <chr>,
#   reply_to_user_id <chr>, reply_to_screen_name <chr>, is_quote <lgl>,
#   is_retweet <lgl>, favorite_count <int>, retweet_count <int>,
#   hashtags <list>, symbols <list>, urls_url <list>, urls_t.co <list>,
#   urls_expanded_url <list>, media_url <list>, media_t.co <list>,
#   media_expanded_url <list>, media_type <list>, ext_media_url <list>,
#   ext_media_t.co <list>, ext_media_expanded_url <list>, ext_media_type <lgl>,
#   mentions_user_id <list>, mentions_screen_name <list>, lang <chr>,
#   quoted_status_id <chr>, quoted_text <chr>, retweet_status_id <chr>,
#   retweet_text <chr>, place_url <chr>, place_name <chr>,
#   place_full_name <chr>, place_type <chr>, country <chr>, country_code <chr>,
#   geo_coords <list>, coords_coords <list>, bbox_coords <list>
```

Note the [Twitter API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets) says "The location is preferentially taking [sic] from the Geotagging API, but will fall back to their Twitter profile." There doesn't seem to be a way in the API to return only geotagged tweets.